# laravel5.1 order result by date (created_at)

Tags: mysql, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-5.1

I would like to order my ticket_replies by date (created_at). Any tipp on how to get the ticket_replies ordered by date (oldest one to the top, newest at least). Did I need to use sortByDesc() or the orderBy() statement?
Tabe design:

```
tickets: |id|supp_id|title|user_id|...

ticket_replies: |id|ticket_id|user_id|text|created_at

files: |id|ticket_replie_id|name
```

controller:

```
            $ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->join("ticket_replies", "ticket.id", "=", "ticket_replies.ticket_id")->where('id', $id)->with(['ticket_replie.file'])->orderBy('ticket_replies.created_at')->firstOrFail();

return view('protected.ticketDetail', compact('ticket'));
```

view:

```
<div class="container">

ID: {{$ticket->id}}
title: {{ $ticket->title}}<br>
status: {{ returnStatus($ticket->status) }}<br>
Ticket created: {{ $ticket->created_at }}<br>


@if (!$ticket->supporter)
    supporter:-<br></br></br>
@else
    supporter  {{ $ticket->supporter->username }}<br></br>
@endif

@foreach($ticket->ticket_replie as $reply)
    @if ($reply->file == null)
        reply text: {{ $reply->text }}</br>
    @else
        reply text: {{ $reply->text }}</br>
        file: <a href="/path/to/file/{!! $reply->file->name !!}">Download file</a><br>
    @endif
reply created at: {{$reply->created_at}}</br></br>
@endforeach 

</div>
```

When I run this code it fails saying:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `tickets` inner join `ticket_replies` on `ticket`.`id` = `ticket_replies`.`ticket_id` where `tickets`.`user_id` = 1 and `tickets`.`user_id` is not null and `id` = 43 order by `ticket_replies`.`created_at` asc limit 1)
```

Did I need to modify my model of ticket_replies for this or did I need to take an other way to get this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like

```
join("ticket_replies", "ticket.id", "=", "ticket_replies.ticket_id")
```

to your query. Otherwise you don't get any data from `ticket_replies` table, as `with()` creates you separate query to select all additional data.

Another option is to take it with `with()` subquery:

```
->with([
                'ticket_replies' => function ($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                }
            ])
```

depends what do you need.

Comment: I edited the first post, I'm getting a violation error using this query.

Comment: change where to: `where('tickets.id', $id)`

Comment: `$ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->join("ticket_replies", "ticket.id", "=", "ticket_replies.ticket_id")->where('ticket.id', $id)->with(['ticket_replie.file'])->orderBy('ticket_replies.created_at')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: Results in `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstO‌​rFail()`